# Classes of measures that are closed under multiplication

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory

Consider the space $\mathcal M$ of all finite complex Borel measures on a segment with norm $\|\mu\|=\int d\,|\mu|$. Assume that a norm-closed linear subspace $\mathcal M_0$ of $\mathcal M$ has the following property:

if $\mu\in\mathcal M_0$ and $f\in L^1(|\mu|)$, then $f\mu\in \mathcal M_0$.

Can $\mathcal M_0$ be characterized as the family of all measures that vanish on a certain fixed collection of subsets of the segment?

*Example*: the class of all measures $\mu$ such that $d\mu=f\,dx$ for some $f\in L^1$ coincides with the class of measures that vanish on all subsets of zero Lebesgue measure.

*Update*: For any fixed measure $\mu$, one can define $\mathcal M_0$ as the class of all measures that are absolutely continuous wrt $\mu$. Then the class of subsets in question is the class of subsets of zero $\mu$-measure.

Comment: Fix the interval to be $(0,1)$, is the standard Lebesgue measure in the closed linear span of $\delta_x$ where $x$ ranges over all of $(0,1)$?

Comment: I have changed the order of words, that's what I meant -ok?

Comment: Nope. The closed linear span of all Dirac measures coincides with the set of all discrete measures.

Comment: @Willie Wong: nothing guarantees this; as far as In know, this is not true, and that is why I think that the answer should be negative.

Comment: Sorry for the wrong answer (which I deleted). Another try: If $\mathcal M_0$ is the space of all discrete measures then
$\emptyset$ is the the only set so that each $\mu \in \mathcal M_0$ vanishes on it. Am I missing something?

Comment: Maybe you are right. I had in mind a deeper phenomenon and I did not look at simple situations like this one.

Comment: @limanac: Okay, now I understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\mathcal M_0$ be the space of all discrete measures $\mu$ (i.e. $|\mu|(A)=0$ for some $A$ with countable complement). This is a norm-closed subspace satisfying the property. But $\emptyset$ is the only set on which every discrete measure vanishes.

Comment: @limanac The comment is no longer relevan and should be deleted.

Comment: That was because you undeleted your old answer and my comment appeared automatically. Done.